# Designing a view for UIPopoverController in the storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, popover

Is it possible for me to design a new view (at a non-standard size, say 300x300) for a UIPopoverController I will use in my iPad app and design this on the main storyboard?

I can't see any way of customizing a view I create on the storyboard. A new ViewController is always the full size of the iPad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Attributes inspector, you can change the size metric of the controller from "Inferred" to "Freeform", and then click on the view and change its size in the size inspector to what you want.